# How to set up GitHub Pages root to redirect to index.html instead of 404?

Tags: github-pages, http-redirect

I've migrated my static website with a custom domain to GitHub Pages from GCP. For some reason, GH Pages doesn't redirect the root `example.com` to `index.html`. Instead, it redirects to my 404 page. The 404 just laying there, I didn't do any special settings.

All other pages are available at their addresses.

What do I need to set up to have the default page be index.html?

I love the ability to have an apex domain, but no redirect upsets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself while I was typing the question. For everyone, who finds this question, here's the important information:

I found out that if I manually added `/index.html` to the root, it would still show 404. If I went to, say, `/about.html` and clicked the index page from the menu I got the correct main page.

Then I figured out that all my pages were actually pointing to `Index.html` instead of `index.html` and my main page in the repository was actually named `Index.html`.

What I did was two things:

- removed `Index.html` starting from capital letter from the repo, pushed repo without the index. Then I renamed the page to `index.html` and put it back to the repo.
- changed links on all my pages so they would point to `index.html` without capital. Pushed, cleared browser cache, and refreshed the page.

**The solution in short**: pay attention to capitalization, GH Pages is case-sensitive when it comes to addresses. The repo is not case-sensitive, you will have to delete the page, push, rename then put it back with the new capitalization and push again.